# Defining a model ring in the water propagate?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I am currently in a situation in which I need to define a model for a system I am trying to calibrate, and currently a bit unsure on how I should calibrate the model.

This is basically the setup:

[image]

I basically put a sensor in a pool of water, there is no condition for where the sensor is in the pool, or where it should be put, or whether what form of "containment" it should form. I will then throw rocks into the pool at different positions, due to the impact with the water will water rings occur, and a timer will start at the impact.

Each sensor then measure the time it took for the ring to hit the sensor, an given we "know" the rate at which the area of the circle changes, we could use the time to determine how far the sensor was from the were rock impacted the water.

How do I based on these experiment make a model, that sets the (x,y) position of the sensors, and outputs the (x,y) of where the rock impacted the water for the whole pool?

And how many experiments should I do?..

and how do i setup the my systems of equations...

So where I've started with my solution, is to come up with an equation that given the distance between the impact point, and the sensor, would somehow provide an solution. We know through physics how the ripples expand in respect to time r(t) should be known, and that the distance = $|sensor(x,y) - rock\_impact\_point(x,y)|$  but how do i given multiple r(t) setup a scheme that outputs and (X,y)..

And what if a third axis was introduced? how would that affect it..

Answer (score 0):

Suppose sensor 1 is at $(x_1, y_1)$ and your estimate of the distance of the rock impact point from sensor 1 is $d_1$. Then you know that the rock impact point is somewhere on the circle with centre $(x_1, y_1)$ and radius $d_1$. Let's call this circle $C_1$.

Repeat this for the other sensors and you have several circles $C_1$, $C_2$, $C_3$ etc. In theory these circles will all intersect at a single point, which is the rock impact point.

In the real world your distance estimates will have uncertainties and errors so your circles will probably not intersect at a single point. So the *real* problem is how to find a best estimate for the rock impact point given uncertain distance estimates.

Comment: but would more measurement not outweigh the uncertainties?